# Spacing not applying to grid of cards. Sandbox included

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

(resize output so md breakpoint triggers and cards are in row) https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-agnesi-tix0g

Trying to get space between each card, but it's not applying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-morning-bo3bj). Not really sure why my original sandbox doesn't work though.